# Excel User forms in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm developing VBA code using Forms. I have a certain button option to let the user select the workbook using FileDialog. The workbook file may contain 4 or 5 sheets itself. I have combobox with empty.

I need to have the sheetnames of the user selected workbook listed in the combobox automaticaly without opening the workbook.

I tried with the following code, but got the names of already opened workbooks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Set myfile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With myfile
    .Title = "Choose File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then
         Exit Sub
        End If
Fileselected = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
With Fileselected
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
            ComboBox2.AddItem Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment `Sheets` refers to the current workbook as you do nothing with `Fileselected`.

You must open the selected file, otherwise how can you examine its contents?

```
Set myfile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myfile
    .Title = "Choose File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Fileselected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Dim doc As Workbook
Set doc = Application.Workbooks.Open(Fileselected)

With doc
    For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
        ComboBox2.AddItem .Sheets(i).Name
    Next i

    .Close
End With
```

Comment: After.AllowMultiSelect you can add `.Filters.Add "Excel Documents", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm", 1` to filter for excel docs